# cms made simple - Discovering the location of methods and properties for UDT's

Tags: cmsmadesimple

While exploring the administration side of CMSMadeSimple 1.11.x, if you go to Extensions, then User Defined Tags, you have the ability to write custom php code by clicking on the "Add User Defined Tag"  link.  Once inside the panel, I am curious to know if there are any help guides to help layout a foundational code practice within this area.  From where I see, I cannot find any training or template source links to actually reference data in this control panel. But if I open an existing UDT that comes with the template system (i.e. custom_copywrite), I see code like this..

```
//set start to date your site was published
$startCopyRight='2004';

// check if start year is this year
if(date('Y') == $startCopyRight){
// it was, just print this year
    echo $startCopyRight;
}else{
// it wasnt, print startyear and this year delimited with a dash
    echo $startCopyRight.'-'. date('Y');
}
```

What does that mean?

also what where do we find more properties and methods to apply or expand in this example or a blank UDT if we want to manipulate any data for the news module?

Comment: As an experienced user you should know that questions asking for external resources or recommendations are off-topic for Stack overflow. So why ask?

Comment: Because this is one of the best places on the web where cmsms developers hang out.  sorry to burst the policy bubble, but I need help, and help in this area is challenging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would definitely recommend the CMS Made Simple Development Cookbook ... https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/cms-made-simple-development-cookbook, has some great worked examples and explains everything in detail. Some of the API has changed a little and some more changes coming up in CMSMS 2.0 but usually easy to find your way around by checking out the API as you are already doing.

Would also suggest checking out http://www.i-do-this.com/, www.rolftjassens.com.

Would also recommend checking out the code in the plugins directory. I've discovered a few quick solutions that way.

As always search and post on the CMSMS forum, usually someone else has solved the same problem or will suggest a solution within a day or so.

Chris

Comment: You hit the nail on the mark when you said to check out the code in the plugin directories.  I didn't think about that, and did everything else you mentioned above.  thank you for that insight.  That will be my starting point for UDT development.  thanks!